# Haskell: Parse Error in nested where clause

Tags: haskell

I have the following code, which implements the sieve or Eratosthenes:

```
primeSieve :: Int -> [Int] -- Returns a list of primes up to upperbound
primeSieve upperbound = filter[2..upperbound] 
  where filter ls indx = 
    let divisor = (ls!!indx)
    let filtered = [x | x <- ls, x `mod` divisor /= 0]
    if divisor*divisor >= last filtered
      then filtered
      else filter filtered (indx+1)
```

I get a parse error on line 4, "possible incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets".

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the indentation of the definition of `filter` which is smaller than what it shoul be. The important part is

```
where filter ls indx = 
  let divisor = (ls!!indx)
```

where the `let` starts 4 characters before the `filter` on the line above. That triggers the syntax error. To fix it you can indent more the `filter` definition

```
where filter ls indx = 
        let divisor = (ls!!indx)
```

a more common format is

```
where
  filter ls indx = 
    let divisor = (ls!!indx)
```

because in this way you don't indent too much.

You can find more information about indentation on the [haskell wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation) which contains some nice visual examples about this kind of errors.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you wanted to write `filter` with a do-notation. You could just add a `do` just after the `filter ls indx =`. However, this code being pure (i.e. non monadic), I would recommend this syntax:

```
primeSieve :: Int -> [Int] -- Returns a list of primes up to upperbound
primeSieve upperbound = filter [2..upperbound]
  where
    filter ls indx =
        let divisor = (ls!!indx)
            filtered = [x | x <- ls, x `mod` divisor /= 0]
        in if divisor*divisor >= last filtered
          then filtered
          else filter filtered (indx+1)
```

... but your code gives me the following error:

```
<file>:13:25:
Couldn't match expected type `[Int]'
            with actual type `Int -> [Int]'
Probable cause: `filter' is applied to too few arguments
In the expression: filter [2 .. upperbound]
In an equation for `primeSieve':
    primeSieve upperbound
      = filter [2 .. upperbound]
      where
          filter ls indx
            = let ...
              in
                if divisor * divisor >= last filtered then
                    filtered
                else
                    filter filtered (indx + 1)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I think you meant to pass `0` as a second argument to `filter`:

```
primeSieve :: Int -> [Int] -- Returns a list of primes up to upperbound
primeSieve upperbound = filter [2..upperbound]
  where
    filter ls indx =
        let divisor = (ls!!indx)
            filtered = [x | x <- ls, x `mod` divisor /= 0]
        in if divisor*divisor >= last filtered
          then filtered
          else filter filtered (indx+1)
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the "in if"?

Comment: This is just a `let ... in` clause followed by a  `if` expression. Nothing magic here.